# Taking a user input in LLVM assembly code

Tags: assembly, input, llvm, bytecode

Just a quick question about taking a user input in LLVM assembly code.  Would it be in the arguments of the main function?  Currently my main function looks like this:

```
define i32 @main() nounwind {
factorial.exit:
  %0 = tail call i32 @factorial(i32 3) nounwind   ; <i32> [#uses=1]
  %1 = tail call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @.str, i32     0, i32 0), i32 %0) nounwind ; <i32> [#uses0]
  ret i32 0
}
```

It computes the factorial of 3 at the moment, or what ever number I put in the spot of 3.  I'm currently executing this from the terminal, but I will make a makefile to execute it eventually.  How do I get it to take a user input from the terminal, I'm thinking I would execute it something like "lli factorial.bc 5", after I compile it to bytecode, and it would give me the factorial of 5.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Go to http://llvm.org/demo/ . Type your code in C. Analyze the output LLVM assembly.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying that.  It's very difficult to interpret and when I try to implement it I get a whole bunch of errors.  I'm getting a lot of errors regarding the i8 vs i32 stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the code on [llvm.org/demo](http://llvm.org/demo) yields the following:

```
define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture %argv) nounwind uwtable {
  %1 = getelementptr inbounds i8** %argv, i64 1
  %2 = load i8** %1, align 8, !tbaa !0
  %3 = tail call i64 @strtol(i8* nocapture %2, i8** null, i32 10) nounwind
  %4 = trunc i64 %3 to i32
  %5 = icmp eq i32 %4, 0
  br i1 %5, label %factorial.exit, label %tailrecurse.i

tailrecurse.i:                                    ; preds = %tailrecurse.i, %0
  %X.tr2.i = phi i32 [ %6, %tailrecurse.i ], [ %4, %0 ]
  %accumulator.tr1.i = phi i32 [ %7, %tailrecurse.i ], [ 1, %0 ]
  %6 = add nsw i32 %X.tr2.i, -1
  %7 = mul nsw i32 %accumulator.tr1.i, %X.tr2.i
  %8 = icmp eq i32 %6, 0
  br i1 %8, label %factorial.exit, label %tailrecurse.i

factorial.exit:                                   ; preds = %tailrecurse.i, %0
  %accumulator.tr.lcssa.i = phi i32 [ 1, %0 ], [ %7, %tailrecurse.i ]
  %9 = tail call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([4 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32 %accumulator.tr.lcssa.i) nounwind
  ret i32 0
}
```

In particular you should look at `%1` (i.e. `argv+1`) and `%2` (i.e. `*(argv+1)`): when you invoke `lli factorial.bc 5`, `%2` will contain the pointer to the *string* `5`.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Though I was able to do it another way, uinsg a "cin" statement and generating the assembly that way.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to do it using a "cin" statement instead of taking arguments in the main method.  I coded it in C and used the LLVM website to generate the assembly.